# Holoviz/Param/Panel : is it possible to change, hide or delete the title of a param panel holding parameters from a Parameterized class?

Tags: python, holoviews, holoviz, panel-pyviz, param-pyviz

I have defined a custom `Parameterized` class the folowing way:

```py
class Myclass(param.Parameterized):

    var1 = param.ObjectSelector(
        objects=['A', 'B', 'C'],
        default='B',
        label='Param1',
    )

    seg3 = param.ObjectSelector(
        objects={
            'First group': 'ZK',
            'Second one': 'ZL',
        },
        default='ZL',
        label='Groups',
    )
```

Whenever I want to instanciate this class and generate a Pane with widgets to select parameters, as per the documentation I use the following:

```py
instance = Myclass()
pn.panel(instance.param)
```

This gives me the following output:

[image: Panel with widget and title]

I would like to know how I could get to modify the title that appears to default to the class name? Ideally, it would be at the `pn.panel(...)` level as I would like to have control on specific title, should I split these widgets in several panes.

See:

```py
pn.Row(
    pn.panel(
        instance.param, 
        parameters=['var1']
    ),
    pn.panel(
        instance.param, 
        parameters=['seg3']
    )
)
```

which yields (and I would like to specify custom titles for each pane):

[image: Panel split in two]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the name as follows:

```
instance = Myclass(name='Different Name')
```

This results in your case in the following:

[image: panel pyviz app name changed]

Please note that can also get parameters without using pn.panel() as follows:

```
pn.Row(
    instance.param.var1,
    instance.param.seg3,
)
```

You can do this for example if you don't want to see the name and just use something like `pn.pane.HTML()` to add a different title.

Comment: I had the feeling that you would be answering this one Sander! Thanks for the answer and the tags edit, it worked perfectly.